# Is it possible to use variables in the Smarty conf file?

Tags: php, view, configuration, smarty

I would like to get a variable from another file, but I don't think it's possible.
Is it possible to get a variable from another file ?

My index.tpl :

```
{config_load file="../../config/config.conf" section="client"}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <title>{#pageTitle#}</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

My config.conf :

```
[client]
pageTitle= {$title}
```

CurrentIy, I assign my values with the assign() method

```
 $smarty->assign('pageTitle', $pageTitle);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Do it in PHP.
   readfile, explode, asssign to Smarty

2.try ti include this file as Smarty templale {include file="../../config/config.conf"} and take need variables by smarty modificators